# Extracting a part of a Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a particular cell for example

```
CN=Cloud Test1,OU=Corp,OU=BT-Users,OU=BTATTER,OU=Test,OU=AD UAT,OU=Services,OU=Managed Users,DC=ngco,DC=com
```

The number of OU= varies with different records, my goal is to only extract anything that has OU= infront of it, so basically I want:

```
"OU=Corp,OU=BT-Users,OU=BTATTER,OU=Test,OU=AD UAT,OU=Services,OU=Managed Users"
```

as my output.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you want it in one cell or many?

Comment: You can use Text to Columns, comma as a delimiter, to get the info out of the cells. Then filter/otherwise remove the non-needed info, and then joing back up with `TextJoin()` if you have it. What have you tried?

Comment: @BruceWayne or just TEXTJOIN(), see below. 8P

Answer (score 1):

As an Array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:99)-1)*999+1,999)),2)="OU",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:99)-1)*999+1,999)),""))
```

Being an array formula, it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN() is only available with a subscription to Office 365 Excel.

[image]

---

If you do not have TEXTJOIN(), put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)

    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: Oh yes, it is so obvious! (Clever thinking!)

Comment: Just mimicking what you told the OP to do in one formula.  I am just standing on the shoulders of giants such as yourself. @BruceWayne

Comment: ...Well, shucks.  (Also, just to be clear, you're the giant here! But really, thanks to you and the other folks, I'm even apparently able to be considered above-average-height :P )